# Concurrent methods inside another function in python

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I am new with multiprocessing in python and so far all the example I've seen are this kind (with one or more methods in the file and then '*main*'):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def f1(a):
    #do something

def f2(b):
    #do something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f1(a1)
    p = Process(target=f2, args=(b2,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

If  I have instead a method who calls 2 functions in another file to be concurrent like in the following lines,

```
def function():
    #do something
    file2.f1(a) #first concurrent method
    file2.f2(b) #second concurrent method
```

how should I do?
Can anyone make a simple example? I tried in this way, but it starts all the program again after the first loop :

```
 def function():
    #do something
    for i in range(3):
       p1 = Process(target=file2.f1, args=(a)) #first concurrent method
       p2 = Process(target=file2.f2, args=(b)) #second concurrent method
       p1.start()
       p2.start()
       p1.join()
       p2.join()
```

Comment: Why would it make any difference if you do it inside a function? And what does "it doesn't work properly" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that args varialbe is incorrectly defined, it should be tuple and not a single variable:

```
def function():
    #do something
    for i in range(3):
       p1 = Process(target=file2.f1, args=(a, )) #first concurrent method
       p2 = Process(target=file2.f2, args=(b, )) #second concurrent method
       p1.start()
       p2.start()
       p1.join()
       p2.join()
```

If you the order of the executions is flexible, you can use the Pool class to trigger multiple calls:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

pool = Pool()
pool.map_async(f1, [(arg, )] * 3)
pool.map_async(f2, [(arg, )] * 3)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Thanks Elisha, I tried as tuple but still gives the problem(this time it didnt go inside the for loop). No, the order is not flexible

Comment: @Giuseppe is there a traceback?

Comment: I think I solved it. The problem was that there was not other 'main' in the program. Now I am trying to solve the logging part